# Print the first 1000 Unicode characters in Java

Tags: java, unicode, hex

I need to print the first 1000 unicode characters in Java, the problem is that I don't know how to get together the text and the hexacode for the Unicode.

Example:
I want to print the blank space so in the `println` command I insert "\u00" and in the while loop I need to add the other 2 00, but I can't insert them like a text! ("00").

I give you what I've tried... I've found this code on the internet and I've modified it, and is a little buggy so if you can fix it too I would be awesome ahahah!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char t[]="0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();
    int i = 0;

    while(i<1000) {
            System.out.println("Char: " + t[i/16] + t[i%16] + " ==> " + "\u00" + t[i/16] + t[i++%16]);
    }
}
```

PS: sometimes randomly, the compiler give me this error:

```
at unicodetest.UnicodeTest.main(Char: 83 ==> 83
UnicodeTest.java:10)
```

The line 10 is:

```
System.out.println("Char: " + t[i/16] + t[i%16] + " ==> " + t[i/16] + t[i++%16]);
```

EDIT:
It should appear like this:

```
Char: 20 ==> ' '
Char: 21 ==> '!'
Char: 22 ==> '"'
Char: 23 ==> '#'
Char: 24 ==> '$'
Char: 25 ==> '%'
Char: 26 ==> '&'
Char: 27 ==> '''
Char: 28 ==> '('
Char: 29 ==> ')'
Char: 2a ==> '*'
Char: 2b ==> '+'
Char: 2c ==> ','
Char: 2d ==> '-'
Char: 2e ==> '.'
Char: 2f ==> '/'
Char: 30 ==> '0'
Char: 31 ==> '1'
Char: 32 ==> '2'
Char: 33 ==> '3'
Char: 34 ==> '4'
Char: 35 ==> '5'
Char: 36 ==> '6'
Char: 37 ==> '7'
Char: 38 ==> '8'
Char: 39 ==> '9'
Char: 3a ==> ':'
Char: 3b ==> ';'
Char: 3c ==> '<'
Char: 3d ==> '='
Char: 3e ==> '>'
Char: 3f ==> '?'
Char: 40 ==> '@'
Char: 41 ==> 'A'
Char: 42 ==> 'B'
Char: 43 ==> 'C'
Char: 44 ==> 'D'
Char: 45 ==> 'E'
Char: 46 ==> 'F'
Char: 47 ==> 'G'
...
Char: 37b ==> 'ͻ'
Char: 37c ==> 'ͼ'
Char: 37d ==> 'ͽ'
...
Char: 3e4 ==> 'Ϥ'
Char: 3e5 ==> 'ϥ'
Char: 3e6 ==> 'Ϧ'
Char: 3e7 ==> 'ϧ'
```

Comment: Hmm, many of the codepoints in that range are "combining characters", which don't make sense by themselves. You might want to print them with a preceding base character (other than the single quote that you are using). [Demo](https://repl.it/repls/InsecureRoundTelephones)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a slightly different answer, which doesn't use streams.  You should be able to modify it to produce any output you like.;

I'm using a couple of tricks.  The first is that `char` is an integer and can promote to an `int`.  So to initialize the counter I actually assign it the first ASCII character, which is `' '` (a space).  The first 32 ASCII characters are control characters and don't print, so I just skip them.

The second is that instead of calling `Character.toChars()` I just cast to an `int` to `char`.  This works fine as long as you control the input fully and there's no range errors.

```
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      for( int i = ' '; i < 1000; i++ ) 
         System.out.println( "Char: " + Integer.toHexString( i ) 
             + " ==> " + (char)i );
   }
```

Comment: You can also use`System.out.printf( "Char: %x ==> %s%n", i, (char) i);`

Comment: `printf` is `println`'s fancier cousin and a good function to know too, I wanted to keep things as straight-forward as possible for the OP.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Character.toChars(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toChars(int)) to convert from a code point to representing characters. Below will print all UTF characters between U+0000 and U+03E8, first 1000 code points.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  IntStream.range(0, 1000)
    .mapToObj(i -> "Char: " + i + " ==> " + new String(Character.toChars(i)))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, but where i need to put this?

Comment: it works, thank you so much, but i need to let it appear like this:
Char: 20 ==> ' '

Comment: @Lafa you could replace the `forEach(System.out::println)` with `forEach(a->System.out.println("Char "+ (int)a[0]+":  ==> "+a[0]));`